# How do I add archive folder to dolphin in Xubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu, compression

When I right-click on a folder in dolphin there is no option to compress that folder.

How can I add this to the context-menu of a folder like:

> create archive from folder --> zip,rar,7z,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to install ***"Extract And Compress KDE4 Service Menu"*** to have a context menu to compress and extract files and folders.

[image]

These are the steps:

**1)** Open a Terminal and install these packages.

- `sudo apt-get install dolphin kdebase-bin kdesudo rar unrar p7zip-full`

**2)** Create a soft link to kdesu in */usr/bin* , which is necessary for the script to install the service.

- `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/kde4/libexec/kdesu-distrib/kdesu /usr/bin/kdesu`

**3)** Open Dolphin and go to *Configure Dolphin* > *Services* > *Download New Services*

[image]

[image]

**4)** Search for ***"Extract"*** and **"order by"** ***Most downloads***. Then click on **Install** button to download the service to your machine.

[image]

**5)** Open a Terminal window to install this service.

```
cd ~/.kde/share/apps/servicemenu-download/
tar xvzf 84206-ExtractAndCompress_v1.4.4.tar.gz
cd ExtractAndCompress_v1.4.4/
./install.sh
```

**6)** During the installation choose **systemwide (requiere root password)**

[image]

7) Put your root password and when you have to select a path choose **/usr/share/kde4/services**

[image]

**8)** To finish...Logout and Login, open a Dolphin window and when you click a file o folder you should have a context menu to compress.
eg: **Videos** folder

[image]

hope it will be useful.

Comment: 5) is not neeeded

Comment: It works! even without logging out and in. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install ark
```

Then right click a directory and choose "Compress".